# Написание грамотного файла CMakeLists.txt для компиляции и тестирования библиотеки

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Имею проект со следующей архитектурой:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── Core
│       ├── FiniteStateMachine.h
│       └── IFiniteStateMachine.h
├── source
│   └── Core
│       └── FiniteStateMachine.cpp
└── tests
    ├── Core
    │   └── FiniteStateMachine_tests.cpp
    └── main_tests.cpp
```

Для компиляции в CLion'e написал файл CMakeLists.txt, но файл получился супер кривым.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

get_filename_component(PROJECT_NAME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} NAME)
project(${PROJECT_NAME} CXX)

if (IS_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
    list(APPEND PATH_INCLUDES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
    FILE(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*)
endif()

FILE(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/*)

include_directories(${PATH_INCLUDES})
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

project(${PROJECT_NAME}_test CXX)
if (IS_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
    list(APPEND PATH_INCLUDES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
    FILE(GLOB_RECURSE TEST_HEADERS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*)
endif()

FILE(GLOB_RECURSE TEST_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/* ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/*)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${TEST_SOURCES} ${TEST_HEADRES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} gtest gmock pthread)
```

Сразу оговорюсь что с CMake'ом до этого дела не имел, а в гугле видимо забанили, прошу сильно не ругать!)

Может кто поделится опытом как при такой архитектуре проекта стоит пользоваться CMake'ом?

Для тестирования я использую GTest (gmock), желательно, чтобы данные библиотеки не скачивались с GitHub'a, а находились на компьютере пользователя.

Так же, на будущее хотелось бы уметь исключать из определённых сборок (допустим для тестирования) некоторые файлы (так же для примера: main.cpp (при сборке бинарника, а не библиотеки)) так как в них может происходить инициализация объектов, которые нужно "замокать" в случае тестирования (грубо говоря различные синглтоны и т.п.)

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Нет никаких «правильных» путей использования, используйте так, как Вам удобно. Когда появятся конкретные проблемы, тогда будете менять структуру и спрашивать совета. Лично я бы не стал таким образом включать исходники — я каждый исходник прописываю вручную, но это то, к чему я пришёл сам, **мне** так удобно.

Comment: Я и не прошу "правильный" путь, в моём случае CLion ругается и не даёт нормально собрать библиотеку, хотя если я вручную пользуюсь CMake'ом - вроде всё ок.

Скоре хочется получить некий набор "функций/макросов" от которых нужно плясать.

В идеале добиться хотябы 2 конфигураций сборки. 1 - сборка библиотеки, 2 - сборка тестов, чтобы при этом CLion нормально отрабатывал этот файл, ну а дальше подключить исходники и библиотеки я думаю не возникнет проблем.

Comment: А по поводу исходников на самом деле тоже не всё одназначно. У меня есть проект (достаточно большой) и так уж сложилось что в одной ветке у меня несколько файлов имеют одно название, а в другой - другое (был проведён рефакторинг). Как тогда поступать в таком случае? В CVS данный файл не хочется добавлять, но тот же самый CLion будет ругаться если конкретного файла не будет в CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Я думаю что проблема скорее в CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @MeatBoy в такой случае нужно для каждой ветки свой cmake файл. Использование автопоиска файлов из cmake не очень хорошая идея(на офф сайте cmake  видел что такое не рекомендуют ) и на практике в этом убедился. Уже не помню какие косяки но что то связанное с ребилдом.

Answer (score 0):

Пока что пришел к такому варианту, в CLion'e работает более менее, но приходится собирать  всегда вместе с тестами, иначе пишет что не задан исполняемый файл.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

#--- имя проекта совпадает с именем каталога проекта
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set (PROJECT_NAME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} NAME)
project( FSM CXX )
########################################################################

#--- обработка хедеров
if(IS_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
list(APPEND PATH_INCLUDES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*)
FILE (GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*)
endif()
include_directories(${PATH_INCLUDES})

########################################################################

#--- обработка cpp-файлов
FILE (GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/*)
FILE (GLOB_RECURSE TEST_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/* ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/*)

########################################################################
include_directories(./include)
########################################################################

#--- создание цели проекта
add_library(FSM ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS} )

########################################################################
enable_testing()
add_executable(FSM_test ${INCLUDES} ${TEST_SOURCES})
add_test(FSM_test runUnitTests)
target_link_libraries(FSM_test gmock gtest pthread)
```

Возможно кто-то сможет сделать ревью, подсказать какие моменты можно поправить/улучшить.

Answer (score 0):

Вот ссылочка на гит - там аналогичный проект
https://github.com/beeen007/CMake_tester

Далее наверное знаешь cmake , потом make

Обратите внимание, что в каждой включённой директории многие рекомендуют использовать новый cmake включённый в виде библиотеки в основном файле сборки (да и это лучше для компоновщика)